# How to disable legend click on billboard.js charts?

Tags: billboard.js

How to disable just the click effect on the billboard.js Donut Chart?

I tried different variants, but nothing works.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some variations, I found the solution. This worked for me on billboard.js Donut Chart (v 3.0.3)

```
legend: {
  item: {
    onclick: function(id) {
      false;
    },
  },
},
```

I used the reference from here https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.legend

Comment: how would it be if you want to avoid disabling all data groups so that at least one remains displayed?